# Function/instruction to count number of times a value has already been seen

Tags: r, matlab, programming-languages, dsl, instructions

I'm trying to identify if MATLAB or R has a function that resembles the following.

Say I have an input vector `v`.

```
v = [1, 3, 1, 2, 4, 2, 1, 3]
```

I want to generate a vector, `w`  of equivalent length to `v`. Each element `w[i]` should tell me the following: for the corresponding value `v[i]`, how many times has this value been encountered so far in `v`, i.e. in all elements of `v` up to, but not including, position `i`. In this example

```
w = [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 1]
```

I'm really looking to see if any statistical or domain-specific languages have a function/instruction like this and what it might be called.

Comment: Roland, if you don't mind I will keep the original tags. My objective isn't to use the function itself but rather identify some languages where it can be found. R and Matlab seemed like the best starting place.

Comment: Efficient solution ( O(n) ) should include accumulator array.

Comment: Please study the tag wikis. the instructions tag doesn't fit and the objective stated in your comment would make your question off-topic (you are asking for a tool recommendation).

Comment: In R you could also use `dplyr` like this: `library(dplyr); data.frame(v) %>% group_by(v) %>% mutate(count = row_number()-1)` (the result would be a data.frame but you could easily extract the count column if you need it separate).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In `R`, you can try this:

```
 v <- c(1,3,1,2,4,2,1,3)
 ave(v, v, FUN=seq_along)-1
 #[1] 0 0 1 0 0 1 2 1
```

#### Explanation

```
 ave(seq_along(v), v, FUN=seq_along)  #It may be better to use `seq_along(v)` considering different classes i.e. `factor` also.
 #[1] 1 1 2 1 1 2 3 2
```

Here, we are grouping the sequence of elements by `v`.  For elements that match the same group, the `seq_along` function will create `1,2,3 etc`.  In the case of `v`, the elements of same group `1` are in positions `1,3,7`, so those corresponding positions will be `1,2,3`.  By subtracting with `1`, we will be able to start from `0`.

To understand it better,

```
 lst1 <- split(v,v)
 lst2 <- lapply(lst1, seq_along)
 unsplit(lst2, v)
 #[1] 1 1 2 1 1 2 3 2
```

Using `data.table`

```
  library(data.table)
  DT <- data.table(v, ind=seq_along(v))
  DT[, n:=(1:.N)-1, by=v][,n[ind]]
  #[1] 0 0 1 0 0 1 2 1
```

Comment: And of course this could be done faster with data.table or dplyr.

Comment: @Roland Thanks, I updated with a data.table solution. Do you know if there is any better way in data.table to keep the initial order?

Comment: @Roland, I doubt that converting a numeric vector to a `data.table` object and then operating on it will make it faster. My guess it will be slower. But could be wrong though

Comment: @DavidArenburg With `v <- sample(1:1e4, 1e6, TRUE)` the data.table solution `data.table(v)[, w:=seq_len(.N) - 1, by=v][["w"]]` is faster by about a factor of 5 in my benchmark.

Comment: @Roland, didn't benchmark, but I believe you. You are comparing with `ave` right?

Comment: Yep,  `ave` is a valuable tool with an unfortunate name.  It should be called "do_anything" :-)

Comment: @akrun If you use `:=` you don't need to worry about the order.

Answer (score 7):

In Matlab there is not a function for that (as far as I know), but you can achieve it this way:

```
w = sum(triu(bsxfun(@eq, v, v.'), 1));
```

Explanation: `bsxfun(...)` compares each element with each other. Then `triu(..., 1)` keeps only matches of an element with *previous* elements (i.e. values above the diagonal). Finally `sum(...)` adds all coincidences with previous elements.

---

A more explicit, but slower alternative (not recommended) is:

```
w = arrayfun(@(n) sum(v(1:n-1)==v(n)), 1:numel(v));
```

Explanation: for each index `n` (where `n` varies as `1:numel(v)`), compare all previous elements `v(1:n-1)` to the current element `v(n)`, and get the number of matches (`sum(...)`).

Comment: Thank you for your solution. It's a pity that there isn't something slightly more primitive in Matlab.

Comment: I agree. But you could encapsulate the `bsxfun` line into a function, so it will be "primitive" to you. As you see in [The Minion's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25401402/2586922), it's pretty fast

Answer (score 4):

R has a function called `make.unique` that can be used to obtain the required result. First use it to make all elements unique:

```
(v.u <- make.unique(as.character(v))) # it only works on character vectors so you must convert first
[1] "1"   "3"   "1.1" "2"   "4"   "2.1" "1.2" "3.1"
```

You can then take this vector, remove the original data, convert the blanks to 0, and convert back to integer to get the counts:

```
as.integer(sub("^$","0",sub("[0-9]+\\.?","",v.u)))
[1] 0 0 1 0 0 1 2 1
```

Comment: That's quite interesting. It's a pity that you have to convert to and from strings though. I think there could be scenarios where this kind of thing would be useful in integer form.

Comment: Interesting approach +1

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use a for-loop in matlab you can get the result with:

```
res=v;
res(:)=0;
for c=1:length(v)
    helper=find(v==v(c));
    res(c)=find(helper==c);
end
```

not sure about runtime compared to Luis Mendo's solution. Gonna check that now.

**Edit**

Running the code 10.000 times results in:

```
My Solution: Elapsed time is 0.303828 seconds 
Luis Mendo's Solution (bsxfun): Elapsed time is 0.180215 seconds.
Luis Mendo's Solution (arrayfun): Elapsed time is 3.868467 seconds.
```

So the bsxfun solution is fastest, then the for-loop followed by the arrayfun solution. Gonna generate longer v-arrays now and see if sth changes.

**Edit 2**
Changing v to

```
v = ceil(rand(100,1)*8);
```

resulted in more obvious runtime ranking:

```
My Solution: Elapsed time is 4.020916 seconds.
Luis Mendo's Solution (bsxfun):Elapsed time is 0.808152 seconds.
Luis Mendo's Solution (arrayfun): Elapsed time is 22.126661 seconds.
```